# How to suppress "This page is accessing information not under its control"

Tags: web-services, security, internet-explorer

I get this message when I am trying to access a web service from Jquery located in SAME the URL (but different directory).

I know it is IE security setting. The question is, how do I suppress it...surely, people don't put web services in the same web site, same directory....

Comment: I notice it happening when the ajax call is using a different protocol than the page, example, page is http and ajax url is https.  Is that your scenario?  Don't know how to solve that yet.  I need my ajax call to always use https (it needs to pass along some cookies that are set in a secure context), buut I can't guarantee the context the main page is being viewes within.

Answer (score 3):

In case this is helpful for someone running Visual Studio 2013. I had upgraded my Visual Studio from 2010 to 2013 and then started seeing the seurity warning.

Using Fiddler I found that VS 2013 kept sending arterySignalR requests.

I turned this off by setting the following in the web.config under appSettings

```
<add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
```

which caused the security warning to go away.

Comment: Unfortunately this one doesn't work either at this point.  Really wish it did, though. (*sigh*).

Comment: worx worx worx worx worx

Answer (score 3):

I know this is caused because of '**Cross-domain data access**'
which I have enabled by

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

In my Ajax call I had to specify `jsonp` as my data type to fix the issue.

```
$.ajax({                    
           url: "xxx",                    
           dataType: "jsonp",
           ...
       });
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working any more when running IE11 in emulator mode for IE 7/8/9.  Just another example of how far out of control the Microsoft (air quotes) security (end air quotes) team is, anymore.  If I *EXPLICITLY* enable CORS in my page, then they should just shut the hell up and give me CORS.

Answer (score 2):

Faced this today and resolved it by changing IE setting and updated the release notes for my application(in case someone needs that)

> Goto Internet Option -> Security -> Internet -> Custom Level ->
>   Miscellaneous(navigate to this section) -> Access Data sources across
>   domains -> Set this to Enable

[image: scrrenshot]

Answer (score 1):

That is a significant security risk that should never be set to enable – there is a large class of attacks online that rely on that being set to Enable; leaving it at prompt reduces the availability of that attack vector…

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem in my HTA (on win 7), and got it fixed by un checking the options below:

`IE (8) -> Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced`

Under the title Security:

```
Warn about certificate address mismatch
Warn if changing between secure and not secure mode
```

After doing this, my HTA didn't ask me again with the popup..

Comment: You can't expect all uses to do this.