# How to overcome this security issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, asp.net-mvc-2, https

I have implemented an ajax-polling script that calls an action in the server Controller every 10 seconds. With the response, I replace the content of a `div`:

```
function getFoo() {
    var link = '/Secure/GetFoo';

    $.post(link, function (response) {
        $('#FooSection').replaceWith(response);
    });

    setTimeout("getFoo();", 10000);
}
```

This is done through *https*. After some time of being "idle", IE displays the following message:

> This page is accessing information
>   that is not under its control. This
>   poses a security risk. Do you want to
>   continue?

If the user clicks *Yes*, the page is redirected to the `div` displaying the response only. If the user clicks *No*, nothing happens, but the `div` container will not be refreshed.

I know [I can suppress this message through browser settings](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-page-is-accessing/ca546963-a4df-4ff0-b524-5d46c1232b15), but that will just bring me to a default *Yes* selection as per the above dialog.

A similar issue has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890565/how-to-suppress-this-page-is-accessing-information-not-under-its-control), but unfortunately there hasn't been any solution. I basically want to make my ajax-polling work even on a **secure** connection. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the page also served using https?

Comment: @ZippyV, Yes. The `div` is inside the page that is being served via https. The response is a somewhat dynamic menu that constantly checks the server for updates.

Comment: Is the page served via https too? (I've only seen this in relation to cross=domain requests)

Comment: @symcbean, They are from the same domain, and https.

Comment: Is the domain exactly the same??? eg, www, vs non www?

Comment: @gnif, yes they are the same. As you can see from my code above, I am calling a controller action to return a response (a piece of html, i.e. `<ul>...</ul>`) to replace the contents of the `div` in the same page.

Comment: Do you have a live demo of the page? Show us if you do.

Comment: @Sleeper, Unfortunately I don't. It's in intranet.

Comment: using fiddler are you sure your post is done by HTTPS, I had a thought that the simple methods of `.ajax()` only post and get through HTTP.

Comment: @balexandre, I tried Firebug like what @Pantelis said. And I could see in the console that the GET/POST are all via https. If you are saying methods like `.ajax()` get through via http only, then wouldn't my original call have issues? I'm confused now... :(

Comment: Do you have an expired authentication token?  Perhaps the server is trying to redirect you to be re-authenticated?

Comment: @gilly3, All I know for now is that when the session _expires_, the page isn't been redirected (to enable re-authentication, see my comment to @Mick Hansen's answer). Thus, subsequent ajax calls to change a content in the page is throwing such an error.

Comment: Will this not work inside an iframe?

Comment: @Oliver, if I put it in an iframe, does it have to use `https` too? I imagine I would have _mixed_ content on my website if I do so.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should never see that dialog on an Internet-Zone page. By default, this operation is silently and automatically blocked in the Internet Zone.

There are two root causes for that dialog to appear in the Intranet zone:

1> Attempting to do a cross-origin request using the XMLHTTPRequest object (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/04/22/ie-security-prompt-page-accessing-cross-domain-information-not-under-its-control.aspx)

2> Attempting to navigate an OBJECT Tag hosting HTML to a cross origin page.

You can avoid case #1 by using XDomainRequest instead of XMLHTTPRequest.
You can avoid case #2 by using an IFRAME instead of an OBJECT tag.

Comment: So we have to come up with two solutions, one for every browser but IE and one for IE. That's just great.

Comment: I think you're a bit confused; all browsers enforce a Same-Origin policy. The question is how your code is actually behaving underneath the JQuery abstraction.

Comment: I *believe* I only had this issue with IE8 but to be honest I cannot remember now. Thanks for the follow up though Eric.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar problem the other day, being unable to find out why IE would complain after an AJAX request.

I used Firebug's net console and just went through the requests one by one till i found one that was http:// instead of https://, i suggest you do the same - It'll be allmost impossible for us to debug this without seeing the page, but it could be something as little as a background image not being loaded via https.

**Note:**
I did notice you saying it was IE, but a problem like this would probably not be browser-specific, Firefox/Chrome just doesn't make the same fuss about there being non https elements as IE does.

Comment: @Mick Hansen, I am actually trying to run this on FF4, closely monitoring the Net console in Firebug. All `get` requests are on `https` so far, no `http` only. Will wait a few more minutes for the session to *expire* then see how it goes.

Comment: @Alex Very strange, if its acting up there really ought to be some non-https request, and it should show up via the net console if you have it turned on from the start - However don't just check get requests, check them all :)

Comment: @Mick, Okay after about an hour I'm getting a [302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) on the same request. Previously it was all 200... This is FF now. I reckon if this were in IE, then I would get the message as in my question.

Comment: @Alex I wouldn't imagine the HTTP Response Code makes any difference as long as it's still HTTPS, strange. Although a 302 is a redirect, maybe the redirect target isn't HTTPS?

Comment: Based on the console, the redirection attempt targets the ADFS server, which handles the authentication. It is HTTPS as well. However, what's suspicious is that it belongs to _another_ domain albeit being accessible within the same intranet. (I'll have a look to confirm.) I am hosting this web app from Azure, if that's of any help... But yeah, redirection to another website is also a viable workaround for me if all else fails.

Comment: @Alex I think we're reaching an area where my knowledge is lacking. But crossdomain shouldn't be that big of a deal for the HTTPS status, else Google Analytics might break it

Answer (score 3):

There's two things about your code :

Why do you use a POST ajax request ? why not GET ?
Your request looks like a GET request (you want to get some data), so the GET method is probably a better choice.

It's not linked to your problem, but you should not use setTimeout with a string to eval. You should give setTimeout a variable as the first argument, and this variable should be the function you want to execute.

```
function getFoo() {
    var link = '/Secure/GetFoo';

    $.get(link, function (response) {
        $('#FooSection').replaceWith(response);
    });

    window.setTimeout(getFoo, 10000);
}
```

Comment: Probably he is using POST to avoid caching.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using *protocol-relative hyperlinks* (`//something.com/image.png`)? See [this link](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200710/httphttps_transitions_and_relative_urls.html) or [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gduthie/archive/2009/11/04/solving-confusing-browser-security-prompts-with-protocol-relative-hyperlinks.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If there is even one element whose src attribute begins with "http" instead of "https" in your code, IE will show that message.

Are you sure that the data you 're fetching has no elements that have src="http:// ... " in their src attribute?

Comment: I verified the expected response, and the elements do not have reference to http only in their `src` attributes. Fyi, I am retrieving an `ActionResult` from the controller. The returned partial view replaces the contents of the `div` `#FooSection` in my https page.

Comment: i think you should double check, even the JQuery JS file should be served from https, otherwise you can get that message.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this happen before because the new content being inserted via the ajax call had links to none secure image assets, any chance this is the problem you are seeing?

Comment: the response I am getting had no images at all. Just `ul`, `a` and `table`. Oh, there are some javascripts as well, basically, a View page without non-secure assests from what it seems.

Comment: Any chance those javascripts are generating the insecure requests?

Comment: Will have to check. But the javascripts included in the returned view is not being called when the session _expires_. The culprit that causes the message above is caused by the ajax-polling script (outside that returned view), which is part of the site's main masterpage.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using absolute url?

var link = 'https://www.yourdomain.com/Secure/GetFoo';

Comment: No I haven't. Would that help?

Comment: You should verify that the request to 'link' is being sent over https. If it is not being sent over https, then trying to use absolute url specified as 'https' will probably help.  You can verify that the request is being sent over https using either httpwatch or fiddler. You can donwload httpwatch here - http://www.httpwatch.com/download/   You can download fiddler here - http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/version.asp