# media query not working after using rspond.js or css3-media.js

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

i tried to use media query in IE8 using either respond.js or mediaquery.js but nothing working for me. after using css-mediaquery.js  from below link

https://github.com/livingston/css3-mediaqueries-js

it throws some error in my page like

[image]

below by media code.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) 
{
.c
{
border: 2px black solid;
}
}
```

after using respond.js also not workinh for me.

i referred the scripts in my page like

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
```

but not working

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: use respond.js to get your media queries working in IE8.

Comment: I don't understand because when i type in google "media query ie8" i get many useful links. So what is your issue with google???

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE8 support for CSS Media Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769493/ie8-support-for-css-media-query)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**take a deep breath and then read below**

Internet Explorer 8 or older doesn't support media query. You can use `media-queries.js` or `respond.js` to add media query support in IE.

If you survived above answer, below are your rescue links :

[**CSS3-mediaqueries-js GITHUB**](https://github.com/livingston/css3-mediaqueries-js)

[**Respond.js GITHUB**](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)

[**CSS3-mediaqueries-js GOOGLE url for download**](https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/)

Comment: Some wise CSS person once pointed out that the lack of media query support is the first media query result :)

Comment: haha.... *to quote in facebook language*, this line deserves **thousand likes** atleast!! :)

Comment: i got some issue after using css3 meadiq queries.js.updated screenshort in my question

Comment: @SivaRajini : there isn't any screen shot in question mate!!

Comment: see this => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290149/how-to-overcome-this-security-issue

Answer (score 1):

IE8 and below browsers will not support media queries. In order to make your webpage work with IE8 and below you may use `respond.js`

[respond.js link](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)