# suppress : this page is accessing information that is not under its control this poses a security risk?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have asp.net page having lots of ajax controls. I am redirect to https:// login page from this asp.net page after session time out. But the page always showing below popup message window when its redirect.

```
    "this page is accessing information that is not under its control
 this poses a security risk"
```

How can suppress this message window using javascript or jQuery or asp.net code?

Comment: Is the browser IE8? How are you doing the redirect?

Comment: Are you accessing a different domain? If yes, please try updating the AJAX URL to start with the same domain name as the site being requested.

Comment: I am redirecting from http:// subsite.samedomain.com to https:// www.samedomain.com

Comment: I am just doing doing _dopostback to server? in between client browser and asp.net web server there is security server will take care of session timeout and redirect to login page.

Comment: Related: [How to suppress “This page is accessing information not under its control”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890565)