# CRM 2011 "This page is accessing information that is not under its control"

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I have the following javascript on a CRM form which is used to grab a local copy of the Subject entity records:

```
function refreshSubjects() {
    sgc_subjectCache = [];
    var options = "$select=Title,SubjectId,ParentSubject";
    SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords("Subject", options, refreshSubjectsCallback, function(error) {
        alert( error.message );
    }, refreshSubjectsComplete);
}
```

But this results in the annoying "this page is accessing information that is not under its control" dialogue.
I'm not sure why as there is no cross-domain posting going on.

Is there a way to suppress this without compromising browser security?

Comment: See also: [How to suppress “This page is accessing information not under its control”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890565)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/crmdevelopment/thread/6e050347-e584-47c2-aab1-8fdf74e8ef1e

Basically, the domain was correct in the database but I was using "localhost" in my web browser, whereas the SDK was using the FQDN.

Calling the site via the FQDN in the browser removed the problem!