# Removing "This page is accessing information that is not under its control" popup

Tags: asp.net, google-font-api

I am building a website using asp .net. The site uses a Google font this is imported in the masterpage like so...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:400,300,200" media="screen"/>
```

Note that I have removed the http(s) from the url.

However I still always get the following error in a popup...

*"This page is accessing information that is not under its control. This poses a security risk. Do you want to continue?"*

I thought that removing the http(s) would ensure that this error would not appear? How do I go about removing it?

I have also tried putting this reference in my css files using an import but I still get the popup.

I don't want to change browser settings as clients can't be expected to do this.

Thank you

Comment: See also: [How to suppress “This page is accessing information not under its control”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890565)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the solution below is compliant with [Google API's Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/terms/).

The error you have is due to a Cross-Domain request (the popup is known as the Cross-Domain Data Access dialog).
To avoid this dialog, you can host the .css file & the related font files on the same domain has your website.