# How to eliminate the Security risk error while accessing other server's information/data?

Tags: angularjs, json

I am getting the security warning while accessing the data(JSON format) from another internal server.

I am calling the $http from angularjs and during the success I am getting the below warning.

Can someone please help me to eliminate one?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to suppress "This page is accessing information not under its control"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890565/how-to-suppress-this-page-is-accessing-information-not-under-its-control)

Comment: @duskwuff This is not the exact thing I am looking for. Even I tried the solutions provided, but it didn't work. :( Thanks for your post.